# Using have_rows() with nested acf fields

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have a question about nested acf fields. I can't figure out a great way to use `have_rows()` when a repeater/flexible content is nested within another field.

Normally, I would access the data like this:

```
if (have_rows('field_with_many_rows')) : 
  while (have_rows('field_with_many_rows') : the_row();
    $title = get_sub_field('title');
    $copy  = get_sub_field('copy');
    ?> 
      <h1><?php echo $title ?></h1>
      <p><?php echo $copy ?></p>
    <?php
  endwhile;
endif;
```

But that doesn't seem to work when the flexible content field is nested within another field.

What's the nicest way to access nested data with `have_rows()`? I like using it, because it's the neatest way to iterate over a field with multiple entries - but open to better strategies..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ACF official documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/working-with-nested-repeaters/#template) indicates it should be as simple as using `have_rows()` again:

```php
if ( have_rows( 'field_1' ) ) {
    while ( have_rows( 'field_1 ' ) ) {
        the_row();

        if ( have_rows( 'field_2' ) ) {
            while ( have_rows( 'field_2' ) ) {
                the_row();

                $value = get_sub_field( ... );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if the parent field is a group field, `have_rows()` will treat it as if it has one row, and you will have to declare the other fields outside the `have_rows()` loop. [This answer](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/cant-get-repeater-in-group-field-to-return-true-with-have_rows/#post-124996) is a good reference.

Comment: what if `field_1` is a group field?

Comment: AFAIK, `have_rows()` will work with a group field. Seems like it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52057378/repeater-inside-group-acf-wordpress

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but how do you access data when using `have_rows()` with a group? I'm not sure what variables are available to me ..

Comment: I added a note about what to do when the parent field is a group (because that was my main concern when asking the question). Feel free to edit!